# Objective-C coding style of the Codename One classes

Tags: codenameone

Just a theoretical curiosity: why is the Objective-C port of the Codename One classes full of `goto` statements and labels like `Label_l12343253`, that make it nearly impossible to be read? It looks like more similar to an assembly language than to an high-level programming language.

Is it an intentional obfuscation of the code or is it an unintentional consequence of the Java bytecode conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the bytecode conversion. Bytecode includes goto statements so that fits better into that. Notice that our port doesn't include that, this is only within the output of parpar VM, not the port code which is hand coded.

In theory we could use heuristics similar to a decompiler to generate better looking code but that might not work nicely for C so we try to be as close as possible to the bytecode.